Why is there attenuation or amplification of the electric field depending on the sign of angle?(Maxwell's equations in free space)
If you solve Maxwell's equations in free space for a complex $\epsilon$ you get this equation:
$\triangledown^{2}E  = -\mu \left |\epsilon\right |e^{i\phi}\omega^{2}E$.
Compared to the equation when $\epsilon$ is real:
$\triangledown^{2}E  = -\mu \epsilon\omega^{2}E$
why when $\phi$ > 0 we have amplification of the electric field and when $\phi$ < 0 we have attenuation of the electric field?

Solving Maxwell's equations means getting function $\mathbf E(\mathbf x,t)$, you only wrote what they imply for a wave that at any point of space oscillates harmonically. When you solve this equation for $E(x)$, real and imaginary part of $\epsilon$ determines how the wave amplitude changes with $x$. Try $E(x)=E_0e^{ikx}$, evaluate the equation for this function, and assuming generally complex $k$,  find $k$ in terms of $\epsilon=\epsilon'+i\epsilon''$ and $\omega$.

What you describe presupposes a set of conventions:

We use the trick of solving the $E$-field in the complex domain and afterwards only use the real part.
In physics we assume space dependence $e^{i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf x}}$ and time dependence $e^{-i\omega t}$ (not $e^{i\omega t}$, which would also work, and people actually use that in electronics, but it requires another choice for the complex $\varepsilon$).
We only look for narrow-band solutions, containing frequencies near one central value $\omega$ so we can use one fixed value $\varepsilon(\omega)$ for this complex permittivity.

If 1) is not true you will not get the Maxwell field (because that field is real).
If 2) is not true, as is the case in the "electronics convention", you would have to use the complex conjugate for $\varepsilon(\omega)$, so the amplification/attenuation behavior for $\phi\gt 0$ and $\phi\lt 0$ would be swapped. It seems that you used that assumption in your question!
If 3) isn't true, you have to use the function $\varepsilon(\omega)$ and express things as integrals over $\omega$.
Example
For the case $\phi>0$, if we look at a positive real frequency $\omega$, we get $$k = \pm\, \omega\,  e^{i\phi/2} \sqrt{\mu|\varepsilon|},$$
so if $k$ has a positive real part, it also gets a positive imaginary part. Using the physics convention, the wave is then:
$$E = E_0\ e^{ikx}\  e^{-i\omega t} = E_0\ e^{i(kx-\omega t)},$$
so it travels to the right and becomes weaker if you look more to the right.
Using the electronics convention, the wave would be:
$$E = E_0\ e^{-ikx}\  e^{i\omega t} = E_0\ e^{-i(kx-\omega t)},$$
which still travels to the right but now becomes stronger if you look more to the right.
So it should be clear: in the physics convention, a value $\phi>0$ means attenuation and with the electronics convention it gives amplification.

If I write $E = Eo\cdot e^{ikx}$ as suggested then by my first equation since im multiplying with $e^{i\phi}$ the result will be $Eo\cdot e^{i(kx+\phi)}$ and since the phase becomes bigger the real part will become smaller which is opposite to what i want.

@ElectronicsBeginner OK, I'll edit the answer to treat this example explicitly! (As soon as I have time...)
